# mapping point on elliptic curve

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves

good evening guys,  let us suppose that elliptic curve is given by the following equation

$y^2=x^3-x+1  \pmod {127}$
on the following table  message  $9$ is converted   to the point on curve

[image]

if i insert directly   into equation , we  will get

$9^3-9+1=721$ and  $721$ mod  $127$ gives me 86, so how 91  is  given? what is relation between  $91$ and  $9$ ? please help me

Comment: You may want to note that there is no $y$ such that $y^2=86\bmod 127$ and as such there's no point with $x=9$ on the curve. _Presumably_ what was done here is that 9 was taken, shifted by 1 decimal digit to the left and then 0,1,2,... was tried for the least significant digit until an x value was found that actually yields a point on the curve.

Comment: http://www.iacis.org/iis/2017/2_iis_2017_103-112.pdf  it is here

Comment: @SEJPM  could you elaborate a bit more please, how it is done?

Comment: They claim that they use encoding from [Mapping an Arbitrary Message to an Elliptic
Curve when Defined over GF(2^n
)](http://ijns.jalaxy.com.tw/contents/ijns-v8-n2/ijns-2009-v8-n2-p169-176.pdf). There are many encodings there. Better to ask the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having read the "paper", which is probably just a "publication" the relevant student had to tick off, I'm *pretty* sure that a standard probabilistic encoding of messages to curve points was used, which is usually attributed to Koblitz. Written algorithmically:

1. Pick a message $m$ of 1 decimal digit length.
2. Set $i\gets 0$
3. Construct $x=m\cdot 10+i$. If $i\geq 10$ return with an error, this has probability around $2^{-10}$.
4. Compute $y=\sqrt{x^3+ax+b}\bmod p$ where $\sqrt\cdot$ is a *modular square root*, ie $(\sqrt x\cdot \sqrt x)\bmod p=x$. If no such $y$ exists, set $i\gets i+1$ and go to 3.
5. return $(x,y)$

Decoding a curve point can then be achieved by finding the decimal representation and cutting the last digit off.

Comment: Note that this can easily be extended beyond "1 decimal digit" and to use bits / bytes instead of decimal digits and to allow error probabilities of around $2^{-256}$ by sacrificing one byte of message space.

Comment: I just [found](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9*x+%2B1%3D91++mod+127) that 10 works and saw your post :)